# What's an effective strategy for purchasing large numbers of different bricks?

Tags: shopping

If you want to go on bricklink for example, you search by part but the end up with parts on various different stores. Buying on ebay is extremely expensive for groups of different parts. How do you deal with it?

Comment: Welcome to this site! I hope you don't mind, but I've edited your question slightly to make it slightly less subjective, and therefore a better fit for this site.

Answer (score 3):

On bricklink, your example, if you input the parts into a wanted list it allows you to find stores that have all (or most) of the parts on the list letting you minimize shipping costs.